# rsync daemon failed to start

Tags: services, rsync, openstack

While configuring one of [OpenStack](http://docs.openstack.org/)'s [components](http://docs.openstack.org/grizzly/openstack-compute/install/apt/content/installing-and-configuring-storage-nodes.html) I had to restart rsync using the command `sudo service rsync restart`. Doing this, I get the following error message:

```
 * Restarting rsync daemon rsync
 * rsync daemon not running, attempting to start.
 * rsync daemon failed to start
```

Appreciate any help regarding this.

**EDIT**: The contents of /etc/rsyncd.conf are as follows:

```
uid = swift
gid = swift
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
address = 127.0.0.1
#address = <STORAGE_LOCAL_NET_IP>

[account]
max connections = 2
path = /srv/node/
read only = false
lock file = /var/lock/account.lock

[container]
max connections = 2
path = /srv/node/
read only = false
lock file = /var/lock/container.lock

[object]
max connections = 2
path = /srv/node/
read only = false
lock file = /var/lock/object.lock
```

Comment: Is rsync-deamon enabled in `/etc/default/rsync`(RSYNC_ENABLE=true) ?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled, RSYNC_ENABLE=true.

Comment: Ok, have you created the config-file `/etc/rsyncd.conf`? Please edit your question and post the config.

Comment: What does the log say after you tried to start rsync?

Comment: Can you please tell me the path where rsync's logs are stored?

Comment: You have set the path in your config: `log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log`

Comment: @prophecy201: Bloopers! Perhaps because I had directly copied the contents from the guide given as link above, it escaped my vision. Anyways, a reboot of my system has corrected the issue. Thanks for your patience and effort! Probably should be closed as localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting the machine actually helped me. Unfortunately, I could not figure what exactly went wrong. However, have a look at the following before you bang your head in frustration:

1. Check the config file located at `/etc/rsyncd.conf` for minute typos.
2. The log file can give you subtle details of why rsync is failing to start, check the logs. They are located where you have configured them in the config file `/etc/rsyncd.conf`. Mine were in `/var/log/rsyncd.log`.